# How to print barcode labels on standard printer?

Tags: files

I am using **barcode creation module** to create barcode labels on standard printer.while giving print option it is not showing any barcode labels on print preview.

How can i able to see my labels?

It shows this error.

> The directory **/var/www/html/transgenic/sites/default/files/barcodes** is not writable or not exist or something else wrong. You can not print barcodes without correct settings.
> An error occurred while generating the barcode.
> The directory **/var/www/html/transgenic/sites/default/files/barcodes** is not writable or not exist or something else wrong. You can not print barcodes without correct settings.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the permissions right. try 'chmod 755 -R /var/www/html/transgenic/sites/default/files/barcodes' Do this with the same account as the webserver uses.